# Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra - default file transfer mode issues

Tags: samsung, usb, file-transfer

I just got a Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra, I tried moving some files using the usb-c cable. Thankfully, I have usb-c type port in my laptop. I attached it, and a lot of issues started.

**The default USB settings** for the phone are: connection controlled by the phone, file transfer - auto android. (I apologize if those aren't perfect translations, I am using the phone in my native language)

With those settings, I can't get anything done. Trying to look at pictures, disconnection after 2 seconds. Trying to move files, same thing.

After a lot of cursing and trying, I McGyvered this solution. If I connect the phone, then change the settings to "controlled by phone, pictures transfer" for a second and then back to the so called "default" settings, "controlled by phone, files transfer - auto android" - it works fine.

**My question:**
What can cause this? Why aren't the "default" settings actually default? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: For a PC connection all modes that contain "controlled by phone" are wrong. Those modes are for direct connections via OTG, for example to a USB stick. When connected to a PC just use *File transfer*.

Comment: It's a separate settings. It's not "controlled by phone" or "file transfer". It's one setting with options "controlled by phone" or "other device", in which if I use other device (the computer), the connection automatically fails.